# Kotlin: using GSON "class declares multiple JSON fields named field" while extending types

Tags: java, kotlin, gson

I'm getting an error saying `category declares multiple JSON fields named name` here is the setup;

```
class Categories(context: Context): JsonData() {
    override lateinit var data: MutableList<Category>

    class Category(
        override var name: String
    ):Entry(name)
}
```

This is extended from here;

```
abstract class JsonData {
    abstract val data: MutableList<out Entry>

    abstract class Entry(open var name: String)
}
```

When I try to run this through GSON It wont let me. I've been able work around it, but its horrible.

Where I define `Entry` I override the default serialized name by doing this;

```
abstract class Entry(@SerializedName("kotlindumbdumb") open var name: String)
```

It seems wrong that this is the intended method. Is there anything else I can do to make the code tidier?

Comment: Have you tried `class Category(name: String) :Entry(name)`?

Comment: @LouisWasserman that worked. When overriding fields you don't need to use var/val or override keywords in kotlin?

Comment: Consider the following Java: `class Foo { private final String foo; Foo(String foo) { this.foo = foo; } }` `class SubFoo extends Foo { SubFoo(String foo) { super(foo); } }` In this case, you're accepting it only as a _constructor parameter_ and passing it to the superclass constructor, _not_ having a new field.